# Error 53 when trying to net use a Windows XP share from a DOS machine

Tags: networking, windows-xp, net-use

I have a CNC controller running DOS 6.22 which has mounted to a share on a Windows XP machine which is now broken. I replaced the machine with another one (running Windows XP, too) but now I'm no longer able to mount the network share.

After booting the CNC controller i get "Error 53: the network path was not found"

I installed NWLink NetBios as well as NWLink IPX/SPX/NetBios... on the Windows XP machine but no success so far.

Has anybody an idea how the name resolution works or what i should check?

Unfortunately i cannot change the DOS machine and thats why im forced to use IPX/SPX and Windows XP :-(

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the problem. 
It had nothing to do with the windows configuration!

I simply plugged the Ethernet Cable into the wrong Jack on the DOS controller and it looks like the IPX/SPX is bound to a specific port.